# Stereographic projection when the "North/South Pole" is not given by $(0,...,\pm 1)$?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, transformation

Straight forward enough...  what if  My point is arbitrary, how can I get a new stereographic projection?

Comment: Rotate your point to the north or south, then use the usual projection?

Comment: Yes, true.... in fact, this is the motivation of another question I asked yesterday.  But I just thought that there should be a more general formula with no rotations needed, because in the end you would also have to un-rotate to get back in the first coordinate system.  That's two changes of coordinates, which is not exactly neat or nice to work in practice.  Plus the better question we should ask is, "Why doesn't Wikipedia have this already?"

Answer (score 6):

Let $p=(p_1,\dots,p_n)$ be the "Pole", i.e., center of projection, lying on the unit sphere. The role of the $x_n$-coordinate is now taken by the linear functional $\varphi$ defined by  $x\mapsto x\cdot p$. Note that $\varphi(p)=1$.

Given a point $x$ on the sphere, rescale the vector $x-p$ so that the $\varphi$ value of the scaled vector is $-1$. Then add $p$ to get a point in the kernel of $\varphi$. In a formula, 
$$x\mapsto p-\frac{x-p}{\varphi(x-p)} = p+\frac{x-p}{1-x\cdot p}$$

Inverse map: given $x$ in the kernel of $\varphi$, look for scalar $t$ such that $(1-t)p+tx$ has unit norm. Since $x\cdot p$, this amounts to asking $(1-t)^2+ t^2|x|^2 =1$. Simplify to $t(1+|x|^2)=2$. The result is 
$$x\mapsto p + \frac{2}{1+|x|^2}(x-p) = \frac{|x|^2-1}{|x|^2+1} p+\frac{2 }{ |x|^2+1}x$$